# Python - Read text, parsing data in list into same dictionary key

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I'm new, appreciate your patience. I have a txt file called 'student.txt'. Basically any data (siblings & hobbies) listed under 'name', will be populated in a list as values.

'student.txt':

```
name-> Alice
name-> Sam
sibling-> Kate,
sibling-> Luke,
hobby_1-> football
hobby_2-> games
name-> Ramsay
hobby_1-> dance
hobby_2-> swimming
hobby_3-> jogging
```

Expected output:

```
'name-> Alice': {'Hobbies': 'N/A',
                   'Name': 'name-> Alice',
                   'Siblings': 'N/A'},
'name-> Ramsay': {'Hobbies': ['hobby_1-> dance','hobby_2-> swimming','hobby_3-> jogging'],
                   'Name': 'name-> Ramsay',
                   'Siblings': 'N/A'},
 'name-> Sam': {'Hobbies': ['hobby_1-> football','hobby_2-> games'],
                'Name': 'name-> Sam',
                'Siblings': ['sibling-> Kate', 'sibling-> Luke']}}
```

Code I've done so far:

```
with open ('student.txt','r') as file:

    main_dict ={}
    sibling_lst = []
    hobby_lst = []
    header = 'Name,Siblings,Hobbies'.split(',')
    student_dict = dict.fromkeys(header,'N/A')

    for eachline in file:

        if 'name' in eachline:
            student_dict['Name'] = eachline.strip()

        if 'sibling' in eachline:
            sibling_lst.append(eachline.strip().replace(',',''))
            student_dict['Siblings'] =sibling_lst

        if 'hobby' in eachline:
            hobby_lst.append(eachline.strip())
            student_dict['Hobbies']= hobby_lst
            main_dict[student_dict['Name']] = student_dict
            student_dict = dict.fromkeys(header,'N/A')
            hobby_lst =[]
            sibling_lst = []
```

Output from code above:

```
{'N/A': {'Hobbies': ['hobby_3-> jogging'], 'Name': 'N/A', 'Siblings': 'N/A'},
 'name-> Ramsay': {'Hobbies': ['hobby_1-> dance'],
                   'Name': 'name-> Ramsay',
                   'Siblings': 'N/A'},
 'name-> Sam': {'Hobbies': ['hobby_1-> football'],
                'Name': 'name-> Sam',
                'Siblings': ['sibling-> Kate', 'sibling-> Luke']}}
```

'Alice' seems to be missed out. I've tried appending siblings and hobbies into lists and 'reset' it after a loop. It didn't turn out as expected.
Is there any simple way of doing this without changing much of the above code? Appreciate any help.

Comment: `'Name': 'name-> Alice'` or `'Name': 'Alice'` ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code:

```py
with open("testing.txt", "r") as file:

    main_dict = {}
    student_dict = {"Siblings": "N/A", "Hobbies": "N/A"}
    sibling_list = []
    hobby_list = []

    for eachline in file:

        key, value = eachline.split("-> ")
        value = value.strip(",\n")
        
        if key == "name":
            if len(sibling_list) > 0:
                main_dict[name]["Siblings"] = sibling_list
            if len(hobby_list) > 0:
                main_dict[name]["Hobbies"] = hobby_list
            sibling_list = []
            hobby_list = []
            name = value
            main_dict[name] = student_dict.copy()
            main_dict[name]["Name"] = name
            
        elif key == "sibling":
            sibling_list.append(value)

        elif key.startswith("hobby"):
            hobby_list.append(value)

    if len(sibling_list) > 0:
        main_dict[name]["Siblings"] = sibling_list
    if len(hobby_list) > 0:
        main_dict[name]["Hobbies"] = hobby_list

print(main_dict)
```

Result:

```
{'Alice': {'Siblings': 'N/A', 'Hobbies': 'N/A', 'Name': 'Alice'}, 'Sam': {'Siblings': ['Kate', 'Luke'], 'Hobbies': ['football', 'games'], 'Name': 'Sam'}, 'Ramsay': {'Siblings': 'N/A', 'Hobbies': ['dance', 'swimming', 'jogging'], 'Name': 'Ramsay'}}
```

Comment: This is slightly different from your expected output as I have removed the `"name-> "` and `"sibling-> "`s from the dictionary. If you want them to have those, replace the variable `value` with `eachline` whenever it appears.